# Converting a ms-access front-end to a web-based technology

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Can anyone recommend the best web-based technology/language for rewriting a ms-access front-end? I've already converted the tables to MySql and moved all the queries into stored-procedures. The language will need to be able to handle multiple result sets.

Also, I need the GUI to be as similar as possible to the current ms-access front-end. So the new language will need to have features including full CRUD, tabbed forms, datasheet style sub-forms, combo-boxes and reports.

I've dabbled a bit with html, css, php, javascript and java but are any of these capable or suitable? I've heard that Ajax or jQuery might be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This is a misguided goal.

Web UI uses completely different paradigms because a web front end is stateless, with unbound data, whereas Access apps are stateful and bound. A 1:1 translation will be a disastrous way to implement a UI in the web browser, unless you invest a HUGE amount in AJAX development.

That said, you should look into Access 2010 and Sharepoint Access Services, which allow you to createn Access front end with web forms and web reports that can be run in the web browser unchanged. This would likely be an order of magnitude cheaper than rolling your own AJAX-based replacement.

Comment: I think I'll definitely take a look at Access 2010 and Sharepoint Access Services.  But are you saying its 'wrong' to create a web UI for a relational database with full CRUD? I would have thought that with current web technologies this would be relatively straight-forward.

Comment: I don't know where you'd get the idea that I think it's WRONG. It's just a completely different paradigm from the way Access works, and that means the UI has to be based on completely different conventions. And you have to do a lot more work yourself to maintain data integrity (because of its stateless nature).

Answer (score 2):

We are in the process of doing this. In order to keep the "spreadsheet-style forms" that we have with Access, and which include ordering and filtering capabilities as standard on all screens, we took the decision to go for silverlight + Infragistic toolkit on top of it. Up to now, we have already developped a few screens with these tools, and are quite satisfied with the result.

Comment: +1 Whether or not it's a good idea (see David-W-Fenton's answer), this answer is actually a direct reply to the OP.

Comment: There are Access-to-PHP converters and such that I've seen (and by that, I mean ones that actually convert the front end, not just data), but I've never seen anything that produced anything even remotely usable (at least not in the trial versions that you're allowed to use without paying).